# How can I use mysqli_query inside PHP class?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

How can i use `$connect` variable inside `User` class with out sending `$connect` as parameter or defines `global $connect` inside User class?

And I want to create only one connection is

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '1234', 'mydatabase');
```

**The error**

**Warning:** mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in **D:\xampp\htdocs\mateocode\index.php** on **line 9**

**Example code**

```
<?php
    class User {    
        public $id;
        public $username;
        function __construct($user_id)
        {   
        $sql = "select id, username from user where id = '$user_id' limit 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);    
        if(!$result) return false;

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $this->id = $data['id'];
            $this->username = $data['username'];
        }else{ 
            return false; 
        }   
    }
}

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '1234', 'mydatabase');

if($objUser = new User(1))
    echo $objUser->username;
else 
    echo 'There was an error or user not found!';
```

Comment: As sgt says, the 'right way' is to pass $connect as a parameter in the constructor. This is generally considered 'best practice', and will help you keep track of where variables are coming from in your code.

Comment: Using `$connect` as a parameter is actually considered good practice (google for "dependency injection"). For example, it makes your code easier to test.

Comment: Is there another way with out sending `$connect` to the class? I know this work but I don't want to do this because I'm concerned it will increase memory usage when i have many classes.

Comment: and using `global $connect` in `User` class will increase time processing to search for `$connect` variable if there are thousand of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
<?php
    class User {    
        public $id;
        public $username;
        function __construct($user_id, $connect)
        {   
        $sql = "select id, username from user where id = '$user_id' limit 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);    
        if(!$result) return false;

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $this->id = $data['id'];
            $this->username = $data['username'];
        }else{ 
            return false; 
        }   
    }
}

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '1234', 'mydatabase');

if($objUser = new User(1, $connect))
    echo $objUser->username;
else 
    echo 'There was an error or user not found!';
```

Comment: Is there another way with out sending `$connect` to the class? I know this work but I don't want to do this.

Comment: @Marcus why don't you want to use dependency injection? It's considered good practice.

Comment: Then you can define a base class where the connection will be defined and extend that class.

Comment: I'm concerned it will increase memory usage when i have many classes.

Comment: Then you can make it global.

Comment: and using `global $connect` in User class will increase time processing to search for `$connect` variable if there are thousand of classes.

Comment: The best solution would be passing the `variable` at the time of initiating then.